# Load/Save settings from/to database in PreferenceFragment

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments, android-preferences

Users can add projects in my app and I have a PreferenceFragment for settings of the projects.
This is my Fragment:

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.project_settings);
    }
}
```

And my Activity:

```
public class Settings extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment())
            .commit();        
    }
}
```

The availabal settings for each project are identical but the data should be saved per project (e.g. the project name). So how can I save the preferences to my sqlite database?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is a `Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener` and some magic inside the `onPreferenceChange` method.

Comment: but how to load the preference from sqlite to PreferenceFragment when PreferenceFragment is opened?

Answer (score 4):

Putting this here as none of the other questions/answers on this topic were satisfactory, and I just finished precisely this functionality (connect Preferences in a PreferenceFragment to the database).

Basically, you should set `android:persistent="false"` for each Preference in the XML. You should then load values into the Preferences manually on `onCreate()`, and use `setOnPreferenceChangeListener()` to do database value-updating and Preference summary field updating. You may also have to extend some existing Preferences to allow them to be set with values manually, as some of them (e.g. the `RingtonePreference`) do not have methods to set their values -- they just get them internally from SharedPreferences.